# Can I push to an array while decrementing values?

Tags: perl

I know how to easily split a string and push the entries onto an array, but in this case I need to decrement them all by one as well. I could do:

```
my @valueArray = ();
my $values = "1,7,30";

push @valueArray, split(/,/, $values);

for (my $i = 0; $i < scalar(@valueArray); $i++) {
  $valueArray[$i]--;
}
```

but this beeing perl it seems like there should be a shorter way to do that between the split and push. Is there, or should I stop golfing and just go for the for loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this?

```
my $valuesSource = "1,17,30";
my @decrementedValues = map { $_ - 1 } split /,/, $valuesSource;
```

You don't need to decrement here; in fact, rarely `map` should be used when its inner block updates the values of original array elements - and vice versa. )

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to decrement each numeric value of an array by if I understand your code correctly. This can be very easily achieved by using [`map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html).

I'd do it this way if your array really contains only numbers:

```
my @num = qw/1 7 30/;
@num = map { --$_ } @num;
```

**EDIT:**

Maybe you should also check if you are really working on an integer values. For example:

```
my $source = "1,17,30,,a";
say for grep{defined $_} map { /^\d+$/ ? --$_ : undef } split /,/, $source;
```

Comment: `grep defined, ..` looks prettier, but why not reverse the order? `say for map --$_, grep /^\d+$/, split /,/, $source`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it in place, the `for` loop can be made far more succinct:

```
--$_ for @valueArray;
```

This is equivalent to saying:

```
for my $x (@valueArray) {
    --$x;
}
```

In general, you should avoid C-style `for` loops in Perl, as they’re less readable than their range-based equivalents. If you want a non-mutating equivalent that returns a modified copy of the array rather than modifying it in place, there is also `map`:

```
@valueArray = map { $_ - 1 } split /,/, $values;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the [map function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html):

```
my @valueArray = ();
my $values = "1,7,30";
push @valueArray, map { --$_ } split(/,/, $values);
```

Note that when using functions like split or map, you don't need to use push... because split and map can give results in an array context, simply assign directly to the array variable:

```
my $values = "1,7,30";
my @valueArray = map { --$_ } split( /,/, $values);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings;

my $values = "1,7,30";
my @values = map --$_, $values =~ /([0-9]+)/g;

use YAML;
print Dump \@values;
```

Output:

```
C:\temp> jj
---
- 0
- 6
- 29
```